# Connection between Children in Supernatural

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

I may have simply missed the line, and not have been able to find the location in the episode, but ... in [All Hell Breaks Loose](http://www.tv.com/shows/supernatural/all-hell-breaks-loose-1-1003161/) of Supernatural, Sam says that he knows how all the "special children" are connected (not by mothers burned by Yellow Eyes 6 months after birth).  Before he says how though the plot picks up and, from what I recall, he never finishes the thought.

How are the special children connected?

I just started watching the series from the beginning after catching some reruns - great show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the *original (and misleading)* connection, as stated in Season 2, and then the *true* connection, as stated in Seasons 4/5.

**Season 2:**

Throughout this season we learn more and more about these *special children*. At first it seemed that all their parents had been burned by the *Yellowed Eyed Demon* (aka **[Azazel](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Azazel)**), but it soon becomes clear there are exceptions to this (for example [Ava Wilson](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Ava_Wilson), whose mother was still alive). All we know about them is that they all have psychic abilities and the Azazel supposedly wants them to lead an army:

> **YED**: I’m trying to help you. That’s why we’re talking. You’re the one
>   I’m rooting for.
>   **SAM**: What’s that supposed to mean?
>   **YED**: Welcome to
>   the Miss America pageant. Why do you think you’re here? This is a
>   competition. Only one of you crazy kids is gonna make it out of here
>   alive.
>   **SAM**: I thought we were supposed to be—
>   **YED**: Soldiers in a
>   coming war? That’s true. You are. But here’s the thing: I don’t need
>   soldiers. I need soldier. I just need the one.
>   **SAM**: Why?
>   **YED**: Well, I
>   couldn’t just come out and say that, could I, Sam? I had to let
>   everyone think they had a fighting chance. But what I need ... is a
>   leader.
>   **SAM**: To lead who?
>   **YED**: Oh, I’ve already got my army. Or, I
>   will soon, anyway.

**Connection:** All have psychic powers. One is meant to be the leader of Azazel's army.

**Season 4/5 (Possible spoilers)**

Once we reach Season 4/5, we learn the *true purpose and connection* between the Special Children. Azazel, in 1972, found the gates to Lucifer's prison and slaughtered a convent of nuns to open it. It wasn't enough however, and he was told to do two things: get Lilith, to destroy the 66 Seals, and *find him a vessel*.

That was the true purpose of the vessels - to be a vessel for Lucifer.

Azazel fed all of them demon blood when they were younger, which made them stronger (as Sam became stronger throughout Season 4 when drinking Ruby's blood. The mother's who were burned alive were those who walked in on the process. Those who didn't survived.

Azazel's *test*, at the end of Season 2, was to find the most worthy vessel. He would be the *leader of the army*, i.e. the vessel of Lucifer. Ultimately, despite his death in Season 2, Sam was left alive and thus the only *true* vessel for Lucifer (as all of Season 5 shows).

**Connection:** All were fed blood by Azazel. The strongest is meant to be the vessel of Lucifer.